# Generate a file with all possible combinations strings of 0,1 of big length without itertools

Tags: python, combinations

I want to generate big strings (up to 1000) of 0s and 1s with all the possible combinations, without using itertools. I have code that works well with strings of length 20, but I have problems with bigger numbers.

```
exponent=input("String length:")
n= int(exponent) #Convert to integer the input
#Define a function to get the calc
def combinations(n):
# If the length of the string is 0 just write "empty string".    
    if n < 1:              
        print("empty string")
    else:      
        for i in range(2**n):  
        # 2 raised to n power gives the total combinations        
            s = bin(i)[2:]
        # Bin converts to binary the number
            s = "0" * (n-len(s))+s
            print(s)

print(combinations(n))
```

When I try with big numbers like 50 I get the following message:

```
for i in range(2**n):
OverflowError: range() result has too many items
```

Do you have any idea of how to improve my code? How can I spend less memory and also try bigger numbers?

Comment: If you're in Python2, would xrange work here instead of range?

Comment: Do you know how many results you are talking about? The universe will collapse on itself long before your function finishes the job. Billions of universes do not have as many atoms as the number of strings of 0 and 1 of length 1000.

Comment: `s = "0" * (n-len(s))+s` can become `s = s.zfill(n)`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski s=s.zfill(n) seems to work better! Thanks.

Comment: @user18081990: the problem is *not* your algorithm; the problem is printing speed, or any other method of representing your results.

Comment: You are looking for a solution to an impossible task. No, there is no solution for it. You simply cannot print 10715086071862673209484250490600018105614048117055336074437503883703510511249361224931983788156958581275946729175531468251871452856923140435984577574698574803934567774824230985421074605062371141877954182153046474983581941267398767559165543946077062914571196477686542167660429831652624386837205668069376 strings, each 1000 characters long.

Answer (score 1):

Since `range` grabs too much memory, just hand-build your iteration loop:

```
        i = 0
        limit = 2**(n+1) - 1
        while i <= limit:  
            print(bin(i)[2:].zfill(n))
            i += 1
```

Note, however, that you're still limited to a universe with roughly 10^79 particles (about 2^263).  Before you put in a large number, `time` a smaller case, and then compute how long your large one will take to print.

On my desktop monster, I can print all string of length 20 in just over 45 seconds.  Scaling this up, I should be able to handle your desired length of 1000 in ...

```
45 * 2**(1000-20) sec
= 2**5.5 * 2**980 sec
= 2**985.5 sec
```

Now, there are about 2^31.5 seconds in a century ...

```
= 2**(985.5 - 31.5) centuries
= 2**954 centuries
```

Or, looking at this another way, I can produce the output of all strings of length 46 in just about one century.  Doing your "small" case of 50 would finish somewhere around the year 3600 A.D. on my screen.

Even assuming a faster rendering method, we're not solving your "large" problem.  My current speed of printing those 20-char binaries is only 23k (2^14.5) per second.  Let's posit a machine somewhat faster than my desktop monster, say a 1000 Ghz machine that produces a new string every clock cycle.  That's 2^40 strings / sec.

Oh, goodie!  Now, with a perfect rendering speed, we can do the 50-char job in 2^10 seconds, or only 17 minutes instead of 16 centuries.  That pulls in the full 1000-char job to

```
= 2**960 sec
= 2**(960 - 31.5) centuries
= 2**928.5 centuries
```

I'm not going to wait for the results.